# SWT JFace TableViewer selection in Windows 7

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, jface, tableviewer

I am using the SWT JFace `TableViewer` component to display a list of data.  I have implemented the `IColorProvider` to provide a custom foreground and background colour.  I provide black foreground text with a light background colour in most cases.  However, in some cases I use a dark background colour with white foreground text.  This causes a problem in Windows 7 in that the selection colour is a pale blue.

What is happening on Windows 7 is when a dark-coloured item in my table (row-select) is selected the background colour is the pale blue selection colour.  However, the foreground colour remains white and you cannot see it (Refer to fig 1 below).

[Figure 1: JFace SWT TableViewer - Row Selected in Windows 7](http://freshwebdev.co.za/uploads/2011/06/TableViewer1.jpg)

1. Firstly, am I doing something wrong here?
2. Secondly, I have attempted the following to fix this (any ideas about the HOT event painting?):

   ```
   table.addListener(SWT.EraseItem, new Listener() {
       public void handleEvent(Event event) {
           System.out.println(event);
           boolean selected = (event.detail & SWT.SELECTED) == 0;

           event.detail &= ~SWT.HOT;
           TableItem item = (TableItem) event.item;
           int clientWidth = table.getClientArea().width;
           GC gc = event.gc;
           Color oldForeground = gc.getForeground();
           Color oldBackground = gc.getBackground();
           if (selected) {
               gc.setForeground(ColourHelper.WHITE);
               gc.setBackground(ColourHelper.WHITE);
               gc.fillRectangle(0, event.y, clientWidth, event.height);
           } else {
               gc.setForeground(Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_TITLE_BACKGROUND_GRADIENT));                 
               gc.setBackground(Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_TITLE_BACKGROUND));                  
               gc.fillGradientRectangle(0, event.y, clientWidth, event.height, true);
           }

           gc.setForeground(oldForeground);
           gc.setBackground(oldBackground);
           event.detail &= ~SWT.SELECTED;
       }
   });
   ```

When I re-run my test application I get the following.  The selected row is fixed now but there is still a problem with the table-row that is "hovered" over as seen in figure 2.  I have tried to capture the SWT.HOT event within the EraseItem handler, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

[Figure 2: JFace SWT TableViewer - Added EraseItem Event Handler](http://freshwebdev.co.za/uploads/2011/06/TableViewer2.jpg)

I did have some luck adding the PaintItem event handler (as shown below), but I will have to place the same logic regarding cell-alignment in this code for it to render properly.  In addition, my paint event fires and paints over the correctly rendering SELECTED Windows 7 Colour fix.

```
table.addListener(SWT.PaintItem, new Listener() {
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {

        boolean hot = (event.detail & SWT.HOT) == 0;
        if (hot) System.out.println("HOT!");
        if ((event.detail & SWT.HOT & ~SWT.SELECTED) == 0)
            return;
        event.detail &= ~SWT.HOT;
        final int TEXT_MARGIN = 3;
        GC gc = event.gc;

        gc.setForeground(ColourHelper.BLACK);
        gc.setBackground(ColourHelper.BLACK);

        TableItem item = (TableItem) event.item;
        item.setBackground(ColourHelper.BLACK);
        item.setForeground(ColourHelper.BLACK);
        String text = item.getText(event.index);
        int yOffset = 0;
        if (event.index == 1) {
            Point size = event.gc.textExtent(text);
            yOffset = Math.max(0, (event.height - size.y) / 2);
        }
        event.gc.drawText(text, event.x + TEXT_MARGIN, event.y + yOffset, true);
    }
});
```

In summary, perhaps I am doing something wrong with the `IColourProvider` and it's that simple? Alternatively, there is a bug within the `Table` or `TableViewer` component. I have upgraded to the latest by downloading the RCP 3.6.1, but I have the same symptoms.

Some help would be much appreciated :-)